# Track users and keywords with twitter streaming api twython

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, twython

Currently I have

```
stream.statuses.filter(track=['words','I',"want','to','track'])
```

How do I also follow some users at the same time?

Comment: Please be more specific and I will try to help you out.  Are you specifically referring to following different users or only tracking specific users?

Comment: Tracking. All tweets by a set of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `, follow=USERNAME` after your list of words to track in `steam.statuses.filter` to give you :

```
stream.statuses.filter(track=['words','I',"want','to','track'], follow=USERNAME)
```